# Mongodb connection constantly ends

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I've got mongodb running on a standard AWS Ubuntu 14.04 server. After some seemingly unrelated server administration (upgrading, installing python virtualenv etc.) I got some trouble with mongodb. After I resolved one issue (similar to this one) I now got the next one.

When I start the server (`sudo service mongodb restart`) I get the following logs:

```
Wed Dec 23 15:15:14.571 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=21554 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ip-172-31-29-10
Wed Dec 23 15:15:14.571 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.9
Wed Dec 23 15:15:14.571 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Wed Dec 23 15:15:14.571 [initandlisten] build info: Linux orlo 3.2.0-58-generic #88-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 3 17:37:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_54
Wed Dec 23 15:15:14.571 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Wed Dec 23 15:15:14.571 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: "true", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" }
Wed Dec 23 15:15:14.575 [initandlisten] journal dir=/var/lib/mongodb/journal
Wed Dec 23 15:15:14.575 [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
Wed Dec 23 15:15:14.593 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Wed Dec 23 15:15:14.593 [websvr] admin web console waiting for connections on port 28017
Wed Dec 23 15:15:15.337 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:45356 #1 (1 connection now open)
Wed Dec 23 15:15:15.850 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:45356 (0 connections now open)
Wed Dec 23 15:15:16.191 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:45360 #2 (1 connection now open)
Wed Dec 23 15:15:16.788 [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:45360 (0 connections now open)
Wed Dec 23 15:15:17.130 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:45364 #3 (1 connection now open)
Wed Dec 23 15:15:18.108 [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:45364 (0 connections now open)
Wed Dec 23 15:15:18.439 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:45368 #4 (1 connection now open)
Wed Dec 23 15:15:18.934 [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:45368 (0 connections now open)
etc. 
etc.
```

As you can see it constantly opens and closes a connection and I have no idea why. I searched around for an answer, but I can't seem to find anything related.

Does anybody know what could be the trouble here?! Although it's not a production server, people do need to use it in a little while. All tips are welcome!